# Importing subdirectory as go module

Tags: go

I'm trying to import go module from subdirectory. My repository looks like

```
+$ tree .
.
└── bar
    ├── bar.go
    └── go.mod

1 directory, 2 files
+$ cat bar/go.mod
module github.com/graywolf/foo/bar

go 1.13
+$ cat bar/bar.go
package bar

func Bar() string {
        return "bar"
}
```

when pushed to github this source code runs fine

```
+$ cat github.go
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/graywolf/foo/bar"
)

func main() {
        fmt.Println(bar.Bar())
}
+$ go run github.go
go: finding github.com/graywolf/foo latest
go: finding github.com/graywolf/foo/bar latest
go: downloading github.com/graywolf/foo v0.0.0-20191019144834-ffb419608ae6
go: extracting github.com/graywolf/foo v0.0.0-20191019144834-ffb419608ae6
bar
```

However it stops working when I push it to different git hosting. I tweak the url

```
diff --git a/bar/go.mod b/bar/go.mod
index 7407848..6134a24 100644
--- a/bar/go.mod
+++ b/bar/go.mod
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
-module github.com/graywolf/foo/bar
+module git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo/bar

 go 1.13
```

commit and push it and try to run it

```
+$ cat sr.go
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo/bar"
)

func main() {
        fmt.Println(bar.Bar())
}
+$ go run sr.go
go: finding git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo latest
go: downloading git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo v0.0.0-20191019153505-33a4721605aa
go: extracting git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo v0.0.0-20191019153505-33a4721605aa
build command-line-arguments: cannot load git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo/bar: module git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo@latest (v0.0.0-20191019153505-33a4721605aa) found, but does not contain package git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo/bar
```

It looks like github and source hut provide different go-import meta tag, notice the missing `.git` for source hut.

```
+$ curl -sSf https://github.com/graywolf/foo?go-get=1 | grep -A1 go-import
  <meta name="go-import" content="github.com/graywolf/foo git https://github.com/graywolf/foo.git">

+$ curl -sSf https://git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo?go-get=1 | grep -A1 go-import
<meta name="go-import"
  content="git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo git https://git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo">
```

When I edit the source code to use `foo.git` it does find the module, but provide different error message:

```
+$ go run sr.go
go: finding git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo.git latest
go: finding git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo.git/bar latest
go: downloading git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo.git v0.0.0-20191019153505-33a4721605aa
go: downloading git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo.git/bar v0.0.0-20191019153505-33a4721605aa
go: extracting git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo.git v0.0.0-20191019153505-33a4721605aa
go: extracting git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo.git/bar v0.0.0-20191019153505-33a4721605aa
go: git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo.git/bar: git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo.git/bar@v0.0.0-20191019153505-33a4721605aa: parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo/bar
                but was required as: git.sr.ht/~graywolf/foo.git/bar
```

Btw both (github and source hut) works fine when the `go.mod` is in the root of the repository, issue happens only when it is in a subdirectory.

I guess my question is what can I do about it. Did anyone run into something like this? Why doesn't go just clone the `~graywolf/foo` and not check the `bar` subdirectory?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I'm having the same problem with code on bitbucket.

Comment: Github is special hardcoded, for other hostings something based on https://research.swtch.com/vgo-module#download_protocol would need to be created. I've never got to something working due to lack of time.